# Which HTTP verb is most appropriate for adding/removing a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: rest, http

Assume two tables in a relational database A & B, and a join table C. The join table is empty until relationships are explicitly added.

I'm exposing REST endpoints to add/remove these relationships (add/remove an entry in table C). They don't modify the entries in table A or B, but from a consumer's point of view the association of A to B is as important as the entities themselves. It will *feel* as though a resource is being modified. But what's actually happening is a row is being added/removed from table C.

Which verb(s) would be most appropriate for the add/remove endpoints? POST/DELETE? PUT/PUT? A case could even be made for PATCH (if I take the 'modified' route, i'm not replacing an entire resource, just a piece of it)

**UPDATE:** I'm seeing similar situations handled by creating a new resource (/api/friendships/create|delete). If this ends up being the answer so be it, but the relationship in my case is more like a *playlist* being added/removed from a *library*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the relationships are first-class citizens, the appropriate verbs would be POST and DELETE (or PUT and DELETE if relationships cannot be duplicated, i.e. if only one relationship may exist for each A-B pair). In a RESTful API, HTTP verbs typically more closely match the consumer's intentions than the server's implementation details (which are not the concern of the consumer).

Comment: Ok got it, thank you. Would you suggest in that case changing the uri's from /library/{libid}/add|remove/{playlistid} given that I decide to go with PUT/DELETE?

Comment: @vvmk: Actually, looking at your playlist example I'm wondering if it should be PUT/PUT on the playlists instead. What do your URIs currently look like?

Comment: "/users/{library_id}/add/{playlist_id}", "/users/{library_id}/remove/{playlist_id}" - both will be idempotent. I'm open to suggestions to improve clarity. a user's 'library' is the set of playlists they've either created or have explicitly added to their library.

Answer (score 1):

> Which verb(s) would be most appropriate for the add/remove endpoints?

How would you do it with a website?

The client would probably load some form -- it might have a list of `A` and a list of `B`, or it might assume a specific `A` and just provide a list of `B`.  The user would make their selections from the choices in the form, and submit it.

Since that isn't a [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1), you would probably specify that the method on the form is [POST](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3).

If the client knows what the representation of the relationship endpoint should look like, and knows what URI should be used for the relationship resource, then [PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) might be appropriate -- at that point, you are effectively doing remote authoring.